# Why does using *= on numpy arrays modify the original array?

Tags: python, numpy

The following code demonstrates that using `a*=3` modifies the original dataset whereas `a=a*3` does not:

```
data=np.array([[1,0],[3,4]])
a=data[0]
b=data[1]
a*=3
b=b*3
print(data)
```

gives:

```
[[3 0] [3 4]]
```

the `a*=3` statement modified matrix data, but the `b=b*3` statement did not.
I expect neither of the 2 assignments to modify `data` as both `a` and `b` are defined as slices of data and should therefore no longer be linked.
Is this behaviour intended? If so, what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the flags on `a` and `b`, specifically the OWNDATA flag

```
>>> a.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False   # <--- a does not copy data (a*=3 mutates original data)
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> b.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True   # <--- b is copied (the multiplication b*3 creates the copy)
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

The object `data[0]` is not a slice, it's a writable *view* into the array. 
 Modifying the contents will modify `data`.

> Is this behaviour intended? If so, what is the logic behind it?

Yes, this is by design.  It's intended to prevent copying unless necessary.  If you need a copy in numpy, request it explicitly with `a = data[0].copy()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not specific to numpy but true for any mutable object. See for example the following code which modify a list (the archetype mutable object):

```
a = [1]
b = a
b += [2]
print(a, b) #prints [1, 2] [1, 2]
print(id(a), id(b)) #The same id

a = [1]
b = a
b = b + [2]
print(a, b) #prints [1], [1, 2]
print(id(a), id(b)) #Not the same id
```

So an assignment will create a copy while an operator (+=) will modify the object. The numpy object simply behaves in the same way.